# SQLite : On cascade delete doesn't works

Tags: android, sqlite, cascade, delete-row, sql-delete

I want to use foreign key with SQLite (version > 3.8).

I create 3 bases :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
CREATE TABLE `child1` (`child1_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `address` VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE `child2` (`child2_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `country` VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE `parent` (`parent_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    `name` VARCHAR, 
    `child1_fk` integer references child1 (child1_id) on delete cascade, 
    `child2_fk` integer references child2 (child2_id) on delete cascade);
```

Then inject some data

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
INSERT INTO child1(address) VALUES('Street 1');
INSERT INTO child1(address) VALUES('Street 2');
INSERT INTO child2(country) VALUES('France');
INSERT INTO child2(country) VALUES('England');
INSERT INTO parent(name, child1_fk, child2_fk) VALUES('Smith', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO parent(name, child1_fk, child2_fk) VALUES('Dupond', 2, 2);
```

Then, I want to delete a parent and I expect these childs are deleted:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent_id=1;
```

But child1 and child 2 with id 1 isn't deleted... do you know why ?

Comment: It doesn't work that way, if you delete child1 or child2 tuple then expect all the parents that refer to either of those child(s) to be deleted

Comment: From the SQLite documentation : A "CASCADE" action propagates the delete or update operation on the parent key to each dependent child key. For an "ON DELETE CASCADE" action, this means that each row in the child table that was associated with the deleted parent row is also deleted. For an "ON UPDATE CASCADE" action, it means that the values stored in each dependent child key are modified to match the new parent key values. I want to do the same thing, no ?

Comment: And here "child1" and "child2" are parents for your "parent" table , because your foreign keys in "parent" table are defined in  child1 and child2

Comment: OK, if I want to delete child on parent deletion, I need to set reference on my child. But how ? Need to set foreign key to parent table for each child, i'm right ?

Comment: It won't work for your current schema, IF AND ONLY IF  child1 and child2 have a one-to-one mapping with a parent, then you are better off including child1 and child2 in parent table, which will meet your requirements of deletion

Comment: Damn it... i will delete manually all child table content. Thank you for your help.